# How to rollback effects of php artisan make:auth in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel.

I was in middle of my project. I googled for login validation in laravel 5.

I found this command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

it Created several classes and also modified my welcome.blade.php

there was several code in welcome.blade.php.
Now How to rollback effects of this command.

Please Help.

Answer (score 8):

Look at the make:auth command source code to understand what exactly files this command added or changed and revert changed back.

manually you have to remove following files

1. auth/login.blade.php
2. auth/register.blade.php
3. auth/passwords/email.blade.php
4. auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
5. layouts/app.blade.php
6. home.blade.php

Answer (score 7):

Go to `routes/web.php`, delete the created routes by the command make:auth. Remove these two lines and your project will work fine as before.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.
There is no way you can rollback make:auth command as yet in laravel..
You can remove auth manually be removing auth from app controller and and auth route. And if you were lucky enough to have welcome file opened in some IDE then there was a chance of ctrl+z bcause IDEs keep back in memory,., but other then that there is no way retrieving backup the data.

Comment: Only this answer is correct as far as the question is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

we can simply remove below line form wep.php routes folder.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

you can also remove the view files: like auth folder ,app.blade.php, home.blade.php